# Android Pay checkForPreAuthorization has been depcrecated, any alternatives?

Tags: android, android-pay

[In the link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/Payments), it says it was deprecated, but no alternatives are mentioned.

> checkForPreAuthorization(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, int requestCode)
>   This method was deprecated. This API will be removed soon.

Does anyone know how to check preauthroziation??

Comment: Please Refer Documentation https://developers.google.com/android-pay/preauth

Answer (score 0):

Steps to confirm preauthorization:

1. The Android Pay chooser for the first time display a checkbox saying “Use selected info for future purchases from this app"
2. When you traverse through your buy flow as a pre authorized (Returning) user the Android Pay chooser won’t pop up but you’ll be directed to the payment confirmation page as show in user flow doc.

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/payment-flows

3. As a best practice you can check signing key fingerprint of your app match with the SHA fingerprint in the Google dev console.

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/best-practices#invalid_signing_key_fingerprint